# Smooth loading of SVGs using SNAP.SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, snap.svg

I made a point-and-click-adventure-like website using Snap.SVG. It sort of works! but i'd like to improve it.

[www.esad.se](http://esad.se)
(click on the arrow on the right to go to the next image!)

the biggest problem we encountered (along with the teacher helping me at that time) was to iterate through my collection of SVGs - clicking an SVG causes a new image and a new svg to be loaded into the main page. the solution we used was to point to an array containing the SVG paths **and to kill the old SVG by manipulating the DOM with**

> ```
>   event.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
> ```

which we though was probably not the best solution, especially because it doesn't allow for a smooth transition between svgs.

**would there be a way of using a loading method to implement smooth transitions between my SVGs (for instance, a cross-fade)**?

thanks for your insights.

```js
    var s = Snap("#svg"); 
    var first = "A1.JPG"
    var data = {
      "A1.JPG" : {viens : "A2.JPG", svg : "1.svg"},
      "A2.JPG" : {viens : "A3.JPG", svg : "2.svg", scroll : 600}

    // [... etc]
    
    }

    var currentPath = data[first]
    document.images.main.src = first




    var mySvg = Snap.load(currentPath.svg, function(loadedFragment){
      s.append(loadedFragment)
      s.click(getEventElement)
      window.scroll(0,0)
    });


    function getEventElement( event ) {
      if( event.target.localName == 'svg' ) { return }

        target = event.target.parentNode.id

//      if (target == "noclick") {return}

if(currentPath[target] == undefined) {

 return
}

document.images.main.src = currentPath[target]
currentPath = data[currentPath[target]]
      //this.clear()
      event.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove()

      if(currentPath.hasOwnProperty("scroll")){
        window.scroll(currentPath.scroll,0)
      }else{
        window.scroll(0,0)
      }

      mySvg = Snap.load(currentPath.svg, function(loadedFragment){
        s.append(loadedFragment)
        //s.click(getEventElement)
      });



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just do it with a CSS class.  Change the line where you remove the element from the DOM to:

```
event.target.classList.add('fade-out');
setTimeout (function () {
   event.target.parentNode.removeChild(event.target);
}, 2000);
```

Then in your CSS for the element add:

```
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 1.5s;
```

And add a new style for the fade-out:

```
.yourSvgClass.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: For some reason it's messing up my removeChild function, but it works well at least for the element i'm clicking on. i'm going to look into it this afternoon. Thanks!